# "A O Antagonista" está correto?

Tags: preposições, artigos-definidos, contrações

Reparei que o site "O Antagonista" faz uma interessante construção gramatical ao usar a preposição **a** antes do nome da publicação (que começa com o artigo **O**):

> O deputado Daniel Coelho, líder do Cidadania, também comentou sobre a censura imposta pelo ministro Alexandre de Moraes, do STF, à Crusoé e **a O Antagonista**.

[ref](https://www.oantagonista.com/brasil/daniel-coelho-a-liberdade-de-imprensa-e-um-pilar-da-democracia/)

> **A O Antagonista**, o ex-presidente do STF Carlos Ayres Britto afirmou que Teori era “um amigo querido e um magistrado exemplar.”

[ref](https://www.oantagonista.com/brasil/ayres-britto-magistrado-exemplar/)

Há outros exemplos, o que mostra que essa é uma escolha deliberada da equipe editorial. Isso está correto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está correto. É aliás o que prescreve o [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 (Base XVIII, 1.a)](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo&id=18-1&version=1990). Explicando eles que se usa apóstrofo em coisas como *n’Os Lusíadas, d’Os Lusíadas*, etc. (em alternativa a *em Os Lusíadas, de Os Lusíadas*, que também é correto), acrescentam:

> As cisões indicadas são análogas às dissoluções gráficas que se fazem, embora sem emprego do apóstrofo, em combinações da preposição *a* com palavras pertencentes a conjuntos vocabulares imediatos: *a* A Relíquia, *a* Os Lusíadas (exemplos: *importância atribuída a* A Relíquia; *recorro a* Os Lusíadas). Em tais casos, como é óbvio, entende-se que a dissolução gráfica nunca impede na leitura a combinação fonética: *a A* = *à, a Os = aos*, etc.

Já agora, procede-se do mesmo modo em coisas como *rogo a O que tudo pode, rogo a Aquela que nos protege*, isto é, quando se quer realçar o pronome com inicial maiúscula (doutro modo, escreveríamos simplesmente *ao, àquela*; [alínea b do mesmo artigo](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo&id=18-1&version=1990)).

Nestes aspetos, o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 simplesmente manteve o estipulado no [Acordo de 1945, (pontos 35](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo&id=8-35&version=1945) e [36](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo&id=8-36&version=1945)), que vigorou em Portugal e países africanos de língua portuguesa. O [Acordo de 1943](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo&version=1943), que vigorava no Brasil, parece ser omisso neste aspeto.